# output cache with Sql Dependency Cache in web farm or load balanced environment

Tags: sqldependency

I was just wondering whether any way exists to use Output cache with SQL Dependency in Load Balanced environment or Web Farm Scenario? By this I mean that following scenarios should be achieved:

1. When performing insert update or delete operation, the cache should be updated on both the server right away i.e. either manually or  automatically. here I succeeded upto some extent that my cache was updated on the server where the current Insert, update or delete request is being processed using following code:

SqlCacheDependency dependency = new       SqlCacheDependency("DependencyName","TableName");
 HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);
 HttpContext.Current.Response.AddCacheDependency(dependency);

But when same code was requested on another server using explicit IP address of the server, the cache was not update.

2. Is there any automated way to notify all the servers in the web farm to update their cache by any means i.e. auto notification or explicitly requesting all the server.
3. Is there a specific way to update Output Cache with Sql dependency of a particular asp.net mvc controller action?

Also, I have IP addresses of each servers in the web farm by which each of them can be distinguished.

Thank in advance,

Lalit